# Is it safe to save parent managed object context in an NSOperation completion

Tags: ios, core-data, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, nsblockoperation

I have an `NSOperationQueue` that is serial and `maxConcurrentOperationCount` is set to 1.

I'm creating many operations to process data for CoreData entity modifications.

Inside of the `[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{` I create a child managed object context off of my main context using the `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and correctly assign the `parentContext`

Is it then safe in the `completionBlock` of the `NSBlockOperation` to save the parent context on the main thread ?

Can an `NSOperation` `completionBlock` run while the next operation begins its "main task" ?

Comment: You should try https://github.com/bignerdranch/CoreDataStack. I use it to save private contexts in NSOperations.